# Selecting blank cells with a Fusion Tables Query with IN

Tags: sql, google-fusion-tables

I want to query my fusion table and select any entries with an effective date greater than equal to a date, or blank. Fusion tables does not allow you to use `OR`, but it does allow `IN` .

My query: `"SELECT 'Effective To' FROM "+tableId+" WHERE 'Effective To' IN ( '>= 03/04/2016', '')"`

I would expect this to retrieve entries were `Effective To` is either `blank` or `>= 03/04/2016`. Instead is selects only rows that are `>= 03/04/2016`. If I modify the query to `WHERE 'Effective To' = '')` then it will grab all entries that have a blank `Effective To`.

**Edit:** I tried double quotes instead of singles, and the query couldn't parse, added single quotes into the double quotes and it only returns entries with a `blank` `Effective To` column.

Query:
`"SELECT 'Effective To' FROM "+tableId+" WHERE 'Effective To' IN ( '>= 03/04/2016', /"''/")"` this only returns columns with a blank `Effective To` column.

Why is this not working? How can I select blank cells in an IN operator?

Comment: Single quotes represent a string constant rather than a column in most databases  I don't know if this is true in Google Fusion, but it might explain your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just gave that a shot and now it only returns rows with a blank `Effective To` column. Do I have a misunderstanding of how IN works? I would expect this to function just like an OR?

Comment: I think you are going to compare Effective To = '>= 03/04/2016' rather than Effective To >= 03/04/2016.

Comment: What do you mean? I encased the >= with a single quote since it appears to be required with fusion tables when using it inside of an IN operator.

Answer (score 0):

- First, better to compare data in timestamp
- Second, make query, like:
  "select 'A' From 'TableId' where 'value >= timestamp'"